# How to setup a _id reference on an update mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    brandName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Food', schema);
```

I want to save the userId as a reference of the food collection.

```
const newFood = new Food({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    brandName: req.body.brandName,
    user = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId),
})
```

Now I'm getting this console error.

```
    user = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, use `:` instead of `=` in user

```
user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId)
```